# Node.js - can includes or readFileSync be bypassed?

Tags: node.js

I have the following. Let's say for instance the folder had some config files, would the below be enough to stop people finding `admin.config` for example or is there a way to bypass the `includes` or `readFileSync` functions?

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if([req.body, req.headers, req.query].some(
        (item) => item && JSON.stringify(item).includes("config")
    )) {
        return res.send("Restricted");
    }
    next();
});
```

So currently with that code above, no one can ready admin.config is what I am getting at and if they can how would they? What about server.config or xxx.config. The reason I am asking is that we have this code on our server which we are unable to change. I want the vendor to amend it but they say since we can't access config files directly we are fine but I am sure somehow we are able to but can't prove it

Comment: sure, but then no other data can be sent or received to/from the server which contains `config` in either the key or data, shouldn't really allow arbitrary loading of files using fs as its unsafe, any file could be read on the system not just ones which contain config in the filename, it's not restricted to *webroot*, why not just use express.static?

Comment: Well, the question is more about how someone could exploit the code as in what could they provide in the URL to get the config files if they are forbidden by the `includes`

Comment: its open to LFI attack [*](https://brightsec.com/blog/local-file-inclusion-lfi), so any path in ?file=/some/path/to/file.ext

Comment: I mean strictly focusing on getting `admin.config` for example, how would you go about as unsure how anyone could get it based on what you have said

Comment: Honestly if this is a sensible file, you should place it into another folder out of contact to external world. How about you learn use .env files, this is the correct way, and you can have a safe project, and users can be served with public files as you desire.

Comment: validate just `req.query.file` that it doesn't include `admin.config` or the specific filename, not everything in req.body, req.query, etc

Comment: So currently with that code above, no one can ready `admin.config` is what I am getting at and if they can how would they? What about `server.config` or `xxx.config`. The reason I am asking is that we have this code on our server which we are unable to change. I want the vendor to amend it but they say since we can't access config files directly we are fine but I am sure somehow we are able to but can't prove it

Comment: This `res.send(fs.readFileSync(req.query.file || "index.html").toString()); ` is silly dangerous as it can retrieve any file on your computer that your server process has access to (or possibly even on the network).  Remove it.  Then, discuss what you're really trying to accomplish and folks here can help with a better, safer way to accomplish it.

Comment: My point is that you won't be able to read any config files will you? Just as a first stage - how would you go about reading any of the config files?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to secure your .env file, I do recommend using *secure-env* package, it is used to encrypt your .env file and then can access it in your code.
there is a lot of options for encryption.
refer to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-env

Comment: Well, the question is more about how someone could exploit the code as in what could they provide in the URL to get the config files if they are forbidden by the includes

Comment: This is the correct approach, even @pee2pee disagreed

Comment: Not answering the question though

Comment: There are two ways to answer, a strict answer, or answer whereas guide people reach a better knowledge as a magnificent manual. This is SO main point.

Comment: Strict answer then to the question